# In Flutter, how can we stack and position the images randomly?

Tags: flutter

Below is the image that I like to build but kinda not sure where to start with, is there a plugin that I missed while searching?

I should be able to stack images which should be reasonably visible though they are stacked on each other and randomly positioned - one below the other or one beside the other images depending on available space and scroll them horizontally.

If it's like a lot of code then please guide me in right direction. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll most likely want to use Stack, Positioned and Transform.rotate.

eg

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Positioned(
      left: getRandomX(),
      bottom: getRandomY(),
      child: Transform.rotate(
         angle: getRandomAngle()
         child: Image.memory(...)
      )
    )
  ]
)
```